# DataGridView Backcolors

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

This is with respect to the language C#.

I want to use the last column in a `DataGridView` as a color column.
The Row in the list will have some data and the last column cell of that row will have a color to represent if it is right or wrong, good or bad. (something like that)
Is it possible to do this and how (if possible)?

Comment: What about your code. What did you trying to do. Where you are stack?

Comment: Have not been able to come up with code that works properly(or even close to proper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting datasource, you may use-

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[LastColumnIndex].Value == YourValue)
            {
                row.Cells[LastColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Hope, you have got the idea.